# How to use css :after in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of CSS:

```
.image-wrap:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px red;
}
```

I would like to 'write' this in Jquery. I'm having trouble with `:after` Is there any way of using `:after` in Jquery? Please take a look at my full code: http://jsfiddle.net/WpGsx/23/

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: @j08691 I can't use css in stylesheet or inline(with HTML) with the script Im working on. So I would like to write the css in Jquery. In this case I would like to set :after in Jquery code. So basically do the same thing as you see in the Fiddle but without the css rules on the right.

Comment: The supposed duplicate is about the 'content' its not about using :after

Comment: Did you read the title of the duplicate?

Comment: this is not a duplicate, his main goal is to add a box shadow with inset to/around the image, question should be edited though

Comment: @BoltClock He wants to change 'foo' in to 'bar' and the anwser is  `$(this).attr('data-content','bar')` How does that help me??

Comment: Or even relate to my question

Comment: you should edit the question to ask how to add an inset box shadow to an image using jquery

Comment: @Youss: Scroll down; there's more than one answer to that question. Your question as it is is the same as the other question. That's why I marked them as dupes.

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you:) Got it http://jsfiddle.net/WpGsx/32/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the inset

http://jsfiddle.net/WpGsx/30/

you might wanna check in different browsers

```
var $wrap = $('.image-wrap');

$wrap.css({
    'box-shadow': 'inset 0px 0px 0px 5px red',
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':'0',
    'top':'0',
    'padding':'5px 5px 0 5px'
});
```

Comment: Sorry I can't use addClass. Im screen scraping using Iframes. Somehow addClass doesn't work for me.

Comment: Im working on it to see if that would work..

Comment: Doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/WpGsx/27/

Comment: I know....it has to be inset....

Comment: Thank you:) Its not perfect(padding...) but its a start. Gave you +1 but someone downvoted you..

Comment: I am sure you can figure out the rest

Comment: I understand the padding now...Its basically the same as giving the img a border

Comment: So how is that an answer? :)

Comment: well the way you have it set up it is displaying like a border, it is unclear what the final intention is. I assume the style will not be as simple as this so my answer serves as a gateway into more possibilities

Comment: Ok thanks for sticking around but I really just wanted the inset (which is impossible to set for images)